# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I implement update operation for my app. .apk folder download WebService and i tried manually it works but on program after download .apk folder can not started.I get error device try to install it "program installation stopped" How can i fix it ?.

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(updateManager.updateContext, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + updateManager.apkOutPath));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
    intent.setData(apkUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
    updateManager.updateContext.startActivity(intent);

} else {

    try {

 String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/";
                File toInstall = new File(PATH,updateManager.apkOutPath );

                Uri apkUri = Uri.fromFile(toInstall);
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                install.setDataAndType(apkUri,
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

                install.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    updateManager.updateContext.startActivity(install);
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Prior to Android 7.0, you have to use a `file` `Uri`, such as from `Uri.fromFile()`, with `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` to request to install an APK.

Comment: i tried but nothing change. File download corretly but after that when try to installed it give error.Can it possible for same name old app. on device ?

Comment: @JohnConnor: If you made this change, your error message will not be `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://`, because the `Uri` scheme will not be `content`.

Comment: Yes, i do not get this exception, i should edit my answer but still after update downloaded .apk file does not work.I try it to manually  it works.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question but to prevent this crash happening you can check Is there any applications to handle the `intent` if not create chooser for `Intent`  :

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Chooser"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my tests, using `ACTION_VIEW` does not work on all phones. Some phones will throw an exception `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`

Whereas using `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` has reliably worked on the phones I've tested to date.

Answer (score 0):

How i managed in download

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
            outputFile = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "ABC.apk")
        } else {
            outputFile = File(filesDir, "ABC.apk")
        }
```

And when installing

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
                    val installIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE)
                    Timber.e(intent.getStringExtra("uri"))
                    val apkFile = File(filesDir, "ABC.apk")
                    val apkURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                            apkFile )
                    installIntent.setDataAndType(apkURI, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                    installIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    installIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                    startActivity(installIntent)
                } else {
                    val installIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    installIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    Timber.e(intent.getStringExtra("uri"))
                    installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra("uri")),
                            "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
                }
```

In provider_paths.xml

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="file_paths" path="."/>
</paths>`